# Should I use sudo with the normal user or root or sudo with another user?

Tags: permissions

on a UNIX OS, ex.: OpenBSD (used as a desktop by me only), which one is the best choice in regards to security. I want to run desktop operations (like pkg_add) with root permissions.

<strike>1. having the root user and using it with `su - root`</strike>
 2. having the normal user in the wheel group
 3. having another user in wheel group, so the normal user isn't in the wheel gr. So if running commands as root you need to first "su - anotheruser" with the normal user then you can "sudo pkg_add"

Or are there any other possibilities?

UPDATE: so not "1." OK. But which one then? "2." or "3."?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normal user and sudo, always: you want to spend as little time being root as possible.

As a bonus, the act of sudoing before giving a command reminds you to be careful.

Comment: There's also the possibility of logging everything done via sudo.